# What is the correct way to include my new functions and scripts in WordPress?

Tags: functions, theme-development

To include new functions we can write them in the theme's functions.php. But I have to write my own functions in a new file rather altering the theme's function.php. I can write any custom js action in footer.php, but I need to write it in other file. How can I do this? Is there any correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `require`, `require_once`, `include` or `include_once` functions to include custom PHP files in your theme.

```
require( 'folder/custom.php' );
```

Usually you should keep your custom PHP files in a folder.

Developers [vote against using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use) `require_once` because it is a little slower than `require` since it requires the system to keep a log of what's already been included/required.

Comment: With technology advances since 2008 when that question was asked and answered, this should not be an issue anymore, when used **correctly**. All include functions will be slower, but it will nearly be unnoticeble. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For adding JavaScript code in WordPress, you can create a .js file and include it in following way, in your theme's functions.php

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script